# $.ajax function failing to retrieve data from database while .php file works

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So i am trying to retrieve some data from a database to present them to a webpage. The thing is that even tho I am using the same code as a function I used to retrieve some other data to be loaded to the same page, but this new function doesn't work at all. Below is the code of the script and its php file. the console.logs show me a blank array, and the functions always fails so it always alerts error. Also, i tried experimenting with initiating the variables or not, same results always, so i am kinda desperate for help

Script

```
<script>
    function databasetoaccordion(){

        var arr2=[];
        alert('hi');
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "json",
        url: "databasetaccordion.php",

        data: {exhibitid:exhibitid,exhibitname:exhibitname,exhibitsum:exhibitsum,exhibitinfo:exhibitinfo,exhibitphoto:exhibitphoto},

              success: function(success){
                  var arr2 = Array.from(Object.keys(success), k=>success[k]);
                   console.log(arr2);

                    alert('cool');
              },
              error: function(error){
                  alert("error");
                  console.log(arr2);
              }
    });

    }
</script>
```

databasetoaccordion.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once('dbconfig/config.php');
    //phpinfo();
?>
    <?php 

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM exhibit JOIN painterarrays ON exhibit.roomid=painterarrays.id WHERE exhibit.roomid=painterarrays.id AND painterarrays.username='". $_SESSION['username']."' ";
         $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
         if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {    

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $exhibitid=$row['exhibitid'];
        $exhibitname= $row['exhibitname'];
        $exhibitsum=$row['exhibitsum'];
        $exhibitinfo=$row['exhibitinfo'];
        $exhibitphoto=$row['exhibitphoto'];

        $ar=array('exhibitid'=>$exhibitid,'exhibitname'=>$exhibitname,'exhibitsum'=>$exhibitsum,'exhibitinfo'=>$exhibitinfo,'exhibitphoto'=>$exhibitphoto);
        $c= json_encode($ar);
        echo $c;
        echo 'hope it works';

    }
  } else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: `echo $c; echo 'hope it works';` is never going to produce valid JSON. Doubly so when it's in a loop. You need to create the full array of what you want returned in the response, then json_encode that (and not append random strings to the end of it).

Comment: `dataType: "json",` says that the response **must** return valid json.

Comment: First off it is a bad idea to reuse the same name success, `success: function(success){`, the same goes for error. Use different names.

Comment: @AndyG Why should this be a problem? They (`success`) will never get in each other's way.

Comment: You've misunderstood the use of `dataType` property. [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) says: "_The type of data that you're expecting back from the server._" JQuery can't force your server to send any specific information or data type. If you're sending back something else, jQuery can't convert it to JSON.

Comment: changed the success name, removed/changed the datatype, atm i get this 'TypeError: 'stepUp' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLInputElement'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've slightly modified your code and i got it working on my machine.

Firstly in your PHP file your array needs to have keys and values such as...
`$ar=array('exhibitid'=>exhibitid,'exhibitname'=>exhibitname,'exhibitsum'=>exhibitsum,'exhibitinfo'=>exhibitinfo,'exhibitphoto'=>exhibitphoto);`

Notice the quotation marks around the first value.
Secondly you echoing some weird stuff at the end of the php function. As its being used as an AJAX call the only thing you want to be echoing is the response.

`$c= json_encode($ar);
 echo $c;`

Then in your Javascript file you can remove the `data: ....` line in your ajax call it's not needed.

Finally in your success function you simply want to parse the return

`success: function(response){
    const array = JSON.parse(reponse);
 },`

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: seems to be working. thanks. Also i thought we always needed to place data: . . .  in the $.ajax . even when we are retrieving data. I kinda study a bit and then immidiately write code, until i am stuck at something. So thanks for that clarification too